# Can I remove OverflowAI conversations?

Tags: support, overflow-ai

When using [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/), I have options to delete conversations or rename them.

[image]

Does OverflowAI have the same functionality? I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: Why delete it? Keep it for memory of all the (not so) great times you and the Overflow AI have had together. Such as the time when it told me to run a command to fix my problems, but the suggested command would quite literally destroy my system!

Comment: @Fastnlight That may sound funny, but it is kind of scary that even something as non-AI as OverflowAI immediately starts to behave like Skynet.